# I'm confused about the word "against" in such sentence

Tags: meaning

This sentence extract from Spring document which is a developing framework of program language JAVA.

> However, once the call has finally reached the target object, the
>   `SimplePojo` reference in this case, any method calls that it may make
>   on itself, such as `this.bar()` or `this.foo()`, are going to be invoked
>   ***against*** the `this` reference, and not the proxy.

The translation software trans the meaning as "don't use proxy, but use `this` (`this` is a program term)". but the word ***against*** in my thought is used for indicate opposite, I don't understand.

And why there is an ***and*** after the comma to lead the last sentence? this should be a transition if the translation software is right, why not ***but***?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like so much technical documentation, that passage could use some serious editing.

This is a non-standard use of *against*. It bears some resemblance to this common use of *against*:

> 7 c: as a charge on
>   // charged *against* her account
>
> https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/against

What the author seems to have meant was that the method will be called *on* the instance of the class (which the `this` keyword references), rather than on the instance of the proxy.

The author has a reasonable grasp of English, so I assume that he or she was simply looking for a way to avoid writing "call on" again.  Otherwise the sentence would be something like: "...any method calls that are called on itself...are going to be called on the `this` reference..."

Really, the sentence should have been rephrased.

Comment: it's so awkward, I still spent some time to figure out what as a charge on mean, actually I still have some doubt, haha. And I'm sure I have searched against on merriam-webster, but I ignored that entry because I don't understand that, seems I have so many words to learn, haha.

Comment: @scott, like I said, this is not a normal use of *against* and that definition I provided doesn't actually cover this use - not in my mind, anyway. I was really just speculating about how the writer would have decided to use *against*.  If "charge against" is still unclear to you, take a look at this link: https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/charge+against

Comment: thank you so much for your explanation, that example make me more clearer, and the site looks pretty good. now I feel "via" or "through" maybe suitable for above context too.